# Section of Post URL using wp_get_referer

Tags: php, wordpress

this code is in a WordPress template and does already work to display different custom fields depending on what the referrer page is. But is it possible to use the last word in the post slug i.e,

'-canvas'

'-acrylic'

'-paper'

instead of the whole post URL?
Then I only need the three lines instead of hundreds for all the different store products. As long as the URL ends with these words it displays the correct custom field.

Thankyou

```
<?php

// use the WordPress tag wp_get_referer to assign the referring URL to the variable $referer
$referer = wp_get_referer();

// check if the URL is a specific one
if ( $referer == "http://www.website.com/store/man-woman-faces-canvas/" ) {

  // if it is, do something

  the_field('canvas_description', 'option');

} elseif ( $referer == "http://www.website.com/store/man-woman-faces-acrylic/" ) {
  the_field('acrylic_description', 'option');

} elseif ( $referer == "http://www.website.com/store/man-woman-faces-paper/" ) {
  the_field('paper_description', 'option');

} else {

  // if it isn't, do something else

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use word exist or not method. Please check following code.

```
$referer = wp_get_referer();

if (strpos($referer,'canvas') !== false) {

   the_field('canvas_description', 'option');

} elseif (strpos($referer,'acrylic') !== false){

  the_field('acrylic_description', 'option');

} elseif (strpos($referer,'paper') !== false){

  the_field('paper_description', 'option');

} else {

  // if it isn't, do something else

}
```

Comment: That's perfect just what I need.

Comment: Is it OK to follow up with one more similar question about how to display a custom image field this time using the whole page slug i.e. 'man-woman-faces-acrylic', or 'man-woman-faces-paper'. This lets me show a graphic mock-up of the specific artwork in the canvas, or acrylic etc, on the same template file. Thanks again Arshid